# Go back to start (windows phone 8)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is there any way to make a visual button in my to mimic the start button functionality.
When i press that button navigate  to the Start Screen of windows phone .
Without removing my entry from journal

I don't want to close the application just minimize it. i see the post 
that you told me

```
if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
{
    while (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null)
    {
        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
    }
}
```

This code will close my app . If you press the start button the application continues to run in the background ,without closing the app.

Comment: Don't post same question twice. You have asked same 1h ago.

Comment: The only way I know to return to the start screen without exiting the app is pinning a tile to the start screen.